# What happened to my detailed battery stats on my Asus Transformer Pad?

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, battery-life

I have an Asus Transformer Pad tablet (TF300T). As with any other Android device I've owned, when I go to the settings menu and tap "battery", it gives me a detailed break down of which apps and processes are eating my battery power. Well, at least it *used* to do that.

Nowadays, when I visit the battery settings, only 3 power consumers are listed:

- Screen
- Wi-fi
- Tablet Idle

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of battery settings activity]

Why aren't any of the apps I've been using listed? And what about system processes?

One possibility that occurred to me is that nothing that is using less than 1-2% of the power is being listed, and all my apps are below the threshold. However, that seems unlikely to me as I've played dynamic 3D games and used other CPU-intensive apps at times, and after doing so I've checked the battery activity and they still don't show up.

Before taking this screenshot I was using Pocket, Feedly, Mantano Reader Premium, Chrome, and Words with Friends for hours, alternating between them. Surely some of that should be shown here, right?

When I check the battery activity on my cell phone (A Galaxy Nexus), I see Pocket has used 6% of my battery, and maps has used 3%. And I don't even use those apps on my cell phone nearly as much as I do on my tablet. Yet my tablet is completely silent about them.

It also occurred to me that this problem may have started when I upgraded my tablet to Android 4.1 Jelly Bean about 3 weeks ago. But I can't be sure, and I don't know what to do about it if that turns out to be true.

Can anyone tell me what happened to my battery usage data, and if there's any way to fix this going forward?

Comment: From what I recall, that report doesn't show anything that has used less than 1%. Considering how much of it is screen usage, I'll bet that that's the issue.

Comment: I agree with @AlEverett in general, but there also should now be a new update for the Transformer Pad. Does that resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you ran an Android update recently? You may want to try this app which provides more detailed battery statistics: [Better Battery Stats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats)

Comment: @Al Everett - Based on further testing, I suspect you're right. I can't accept your answer though because you left it as a comment. Want to post it as a full answer?

Comment: @JoshuaCarmody: Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I recall, that report doesn't show anything that has used less than 1%. Considering how much of it is screen usage, I'll bet that that's the issue.